# iText7: Add Text to the top of pdf file

Tags: c#, .net, itext7

I am trying to add a line or two to the top of a pdf file using iText7, I wrote this function, which takes the file path and a boolean parameter (inline):

```
private Stream AppendToDocumentAndReturnStream(string path, bool inline)
{
    string text1 = "Date Range: 3/1/2023 - 3/31/2023";
    string text2 = "Client: Client1, Client2, Client3,... this line may be long";

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
    writer.SetCloseStream(false);

    var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(path), writer);
    var document = new Document(pdfDoc);

    var pageCount = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();

    for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
    {
        PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(page, page.GetPageSize());

        // setting margin-botton to keep distance from original pdf content did NOT work
        var div = new Div().SetMargins(0, 10, 100, 10);

        if (inline)
        {
            div.Add(new Paragraph(text1).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));
            div.Add(new Div().SetKeepWithNext(true));
            div.Add(new Paragraph(text2).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));
        }
        else
        {
            div.Add(new Paragraph(text1).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));
            div.Add(new Paragraph(text2).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT));
        }

        // tried to add this to keep an empty line between added text and original pdf content, but did NOT work too
        div.Add(new Paragraph(new Text("\n")));
        canvas.Add(div);
    }

    document.Close();
    stream.Position = 0;

    return stream;
}
```

However, I have 2 problems with this code:

Problem1: When inline = true, I need to added both text1 & text2 in the same line, with text1 aligned to left and text2 aligned to right, however, text2 gets in a second line! how to keep it in the same line as text1!

Problem2: When inline = false, I need both text1 & text2 to the left in 2 separate lines, however, text2 gets too close to the original pdf content (adding a third line will even get over it), tried adding margin-bottom and "\n" but that did NOT work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for the case when `inline = true` using `Tab` and `TabStops`:

```
    private Stream AppendToDocumentAndReturnStream(string path, bool inline)
    {
        string text1 = "Date Range: 3/1/2023 - 3/31/2023";
        string text2 = "Client: Client1, Client2, Client3,... this line may be long";

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
        writer.SetCloseStream(false);

        var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(path), writer);
        var document = new Document(pdfDoc);

        var pageCount = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();

        for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
        {
            PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(page, page.GetPageSize());

            if (inline)
            {
                Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(text1).SetMarginLeft(8).SetMarginRight(8);
                paragraph.Add(new Tab());
                paragraph.AddTabStops(new TabStop(50000, TabAlignment.RIGHT));
                paragraph.Add(text2);
                paragraph.SetFontSize(14);
                canvas.Add(paragraph);
            }
            else
            {
                // nothing for now
            }
        }

        document.Close();
        stream.Position = 0;

        return stream;
    }
```

Reference:
https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-align-two-paragraphs-to-the-left-and-right-on-the-same-line